Uniform bound involving trace of random matrix
For each ${n}$, let ${A_n = (a_{ij,n})_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}}$ be a random ${n \times n}$ matrix (i.e. a random variable taking values in the space ${{\bf R}^{n \times n}}$ or ${{\bf C}^{n \times n}}$ of ${n \times n}$ matrices) such that the entries ${a_{ij,n}}$ of ${A_n}$ are jointly independent in ${i,j}$ and take values in ${\{-1,+1\}}$ with a probability of ${1/2}$ each. We want to show that for any natural number ${k}$, the quantities ${{\bf E} \hbox{tr} (A_n A_n^*)^k / n^{k+1}}$ (the trace of the matrix power) are bounded uniformly in ${n}$ (i.e. they are bounded by a quantity ${C_k}$ that can depend on ${k}$ but not on ${n}$).
Question: The author suggests we compute $\mathrm{tr}(A_n A_n^*)^k$ as a polynomial of the coefficients of $A_n$, and avoid using the spectral theorem, and that one may work out the first few cases $k=1,2,3$ by hand to get a sense of how to proceed.
By direct computation, it seems that ${\bf E}\mathrm{tr}(A_n A_n^*)^k = 2n^{k+1} - n^k$ for $k = 2, 3$, yet I am not sure how to establish ${\bf E}\mathrm{tr}(A_n A_n^*)^k = O_k(n^{k+1})$ for general $k$ inductively.

just for clarification : 1) Does $\mathrm{tr}(A_n A_n^)^k$ mean $\big(\mathrm{tr}(A_n A_n^)\big)^k$, or $\mathrm{tr}\big((A_n A_n^)^k\big) $ ? 2) $A_n^$ means $A_n^T$, right ? (usually the notation $A^*$ is used for complex matrices, hence i'm not sure if there's something i'm missing)

@Stratossupportsthestrike: (1) We are computing the trace of the matrix power here, not the power of the trace. (2). Yes, the conjugate transpose in this case will simply be the transpose since we are dealing with real matrices.

I managed to come up with a solution which I post below, any corrections or suggestions are welcomed.
When $k = 1$, $\hbox{tr}(A_nA_n^*)^k = n^2$ deterministically and $\displaystyle {\bf E}\hbox{tr}(A_nA_n^*)^k/n^{k+1} = 1$ for all $n$.
Let $r_i(A)$ denote the $i$th row of the matrix $A$, then $\displaystyle r_i(A_nA_n^*) = (\sum_{1 \leq t \leq n}a_{it}a_{1t}, \dots, \sum_{1 \leq t \leq n}a_{it}a_{nt})$, and we have:
\begin{align*}
     (A_nA_n^*)^2_{ii} &= r_i(A_nA_n^*) \cdot r_i(A_nA_n^*)
     \\
     &= \sum_{1 \leq t_1, t_2 \leq n} a_{it_1}a_{1t_1}a_{it_2}a_{1t_2} + \dots + \sum_{1 \leq t_1, t_2 \leq n} a_{it_1}a_{nt_1}a_{it_2}a_{nt_2}.
\end{align*}
Taking expectation, each sum contributes $O(n)$ (the indices need to be paired up in order to have a non-zero contribution), and there are $n$ sums. This implies that
$\displaystyle {\bf E}(A_nA_n^*)^2_{ii} = O(n^2)$, and thus $\displaystyle {\bf E}\hbox{tr}(A_nA_n^*)^2 = O(n^3)$. By a similar computation,
\begin{align*}
 (A_nA_n^*)^3_{ii} &= r_i(A_nA_n^*)^2 \cdot r_i(A_nA_n^*)
 \\
 &= \sum_{t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4}a_{it_1}a_{t_3t_1}a_{1t_2}a_{t_3t_2}a_{it_4}a_{1t_4} + \dots + \sum_{t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4}a_{it_1}a_{t_3t_1}a_{nt_2}a_{t_3t_2}a_{it_4}a_{nt_4}.
\end{align*}
From  which we get ${\bf E}(A_nA_n^*)^3_{ii} = O(n^3)$, and thus ${\bf E}\hbox {tr}(A_nA_n^*)^3 = O(n^4)$.
In general, by the nature of dot product, each time one raises the power $k$ by $1$, the sums in $r_i(A_nA_n^*)^k$ obtain $2$ additional indices. i.e., $\displaystyle r_i(A_nA_n^*)^k = (\sum_{t_1, \dots, t_{2k-1}}, \dots, \sum_{t_1, \dots, t_{2k-1}})$, it follows that $\displaystyle (A_nA_n^*)^{k+1}_{ii} =  r_i(A_nA_n^*)^k \cdot r_i(A_nA_n^*) = \sum_{t_1, \dots, t_{2k}} + \dots + \sum_{t_1, \dots, t_{2k}}$. Taking expectation, it becomes $O(n^{k+1})$.
Consequently, we have ${\bf E}\hbox{tr}(A_nA_n^*)^k / n^{k+1} = O(n^{k+1}) / n^{k+1} = O_k(1)$, as desired.
